# Generate image in a new tab aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

i need my program to open this image in a new tab when it's genenrate it.
here is the genreate code (C#) :

```
    imageFileName = string.Format
(_canvasFolderName + "/canvas_finalsprite_{0}.png", _sequenceNbr);

    string imageServerFileName = 
        HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(imageFileName);
    bitmap.Save(imageServerFileName, ImageFormat.Png);
```

the callingt to generate :

```
    var imgSprite = (Image) (e.Item.FindControl("imgSprite"));
    imgSprite.ImageUrl = _canvas.SpriteToImage(stats.FinalSprite);
```

and this is the aspx code:

```
 <asp:Image ID="imgSprite" runat="server" />
```

i need when it will get to the line         `imgSprite.ImageUrl = _canvas.SpriteToImage(stats.FinalSprite);` to create the image in new tab

also it will be much better if it will be in print mode for this picutre in the new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Make your image an ASP image button

```
<asp:ImageButton D="imgSprite" runat="server" ibnCommand="ibtmImage_Command" />
```

and create a method  to do something like

protected void ibtmImage_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
     string strJS = ("window.open('ItemList.aspx?Id=" + e.CommandArgument.ToString() + "','_blank');");
     Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "strJSAlert", strJS);
}

This can be a local file to your project as well